# Medusajs Dashboard showing a 401 error on login

Tags: node.js, vercel, medusajs

I have deployed my medusajs server on koyeb.com and the dashboard to vercel.com, added envs as shown below:
In koyeb.com for medusajs server
`STORE_CORS=https://shoppica.vercel.app,https://medusa-service-pancham.koyeb.app ADMIN_CORS=https://shoppica.vercel.app JWT_SECRET=A_RANDOM_JWT_SECRET COOKIE_SECRET=A_RANDOM_COOKIE_SECRET`
In the vercel.com for the dashboard
`MEDUSA_ADMIN_BACKEND_URL=https://medusa-service-pancham.koyeb.app`

Whenever I try to login in my medusa dashboard, it does logs in but then again redirects to login page, and in the console it shows a 401 error like in the image shown
[401 error image in medusajs dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7cVEB.png)

how can I solve this?